# Cross-validation for Random forest to select important feature

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
data = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'], columns=data['feature_names'])
df['target'] = data['target']
X = df.drop(columns=['target'])
y = df['target']
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 50, max_depth = 4)

scores = []
print(len(X.columns))
num_features = len(X.columns)
for i in range(num_features):
    col = X.columns[i]
    score = np.mean(cross_val_score(clf, X[col].values.reshape(-1,1), y, cv=10))
    scores.append((int(score*100), col))

print(sorted(scores, reverse = True))
```

I intended to perform 10-fold cross-validation to select most important features. I am confused with my approach. It doesn't seems right! Also, how can I plot those most important features. I appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-machine-learning-python/) is a great source on a few ways to extract feature importance.

Comment: @TylerWanta Dr. Brownlee  did not include the cross-validation part of feature selection! Thank  you so much though!